# x86 simple function not working

Tags: function, assembly, x86

Hi guys I am trying to build the following function

```
function int Main(){
 return 5;
}
```

this is my assembly code:

```
 .globl Main
Main:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $0, %esp
pushl $5
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

However this always returns 1 it never returns 5 why?

Comment: _Suggestion:_ why don't you use compiler to generate assembly code. E.g [GCC](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html)?

Comment: @JacobSeleznev I'm actually trying to build a simple compiler for a class, so I am trying to generate the assembly code. I don't understand what is wrong with the assembly code I generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just:

```
Main:
push byte 5
pop eax
ret
```

Comment: I want it with the prologue and epilogue because I am using a c++ function to generate this code, and I want to be able to use the c++ function to generate multiple functions in x86

Comment: When interfacing with other languages, the return value is expected to be in `eax` as Martin does.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing what everyone said: your primary error is that the return value should go into EAX and it does not. Prolog and epilog code are not necessary for simple functions like this, but they won't hurt either (as long as they don't unbalance the stack). So the assembly should go:

```
(prolog)
movl $5, %eax,
(epilog)
ret
```

Where prolog and epilog are whatever your compiler generates by default.